# Text of List item <li> does not reflected correctly after edited click save button from modal pop up in Javascript

Tags: javascript, materialize

I have nested list item of `<li>` structured as below. What I am trying to do is to edit each item text from pop up modal and reflect change after I clicked on button `Save`.

However, the first list item I edited is working well, but from the second time onward, it does not work as expected.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.modal').modal(); // modal

  var child;
  $('body').on('click', '.fa-pencil', function(e) {


    var text = $(this).closest("li").clone() //clone the element
      .children() //select all the children
      .remove() //remove all the children
      .end() //again go back to selected element
      .text();

    child = $(this).closest("li").children();
    var li_element = $(this).closest('li');
    console.log(li_element);
    var dataActive = $(this).closest('li').attr('data-act');
    var li_icon = li_element.attr('data-icon');

    var modal1 = $('#modal1');
    var modalBody = modal1.find('.modal-content');

    modalBody.find('h4.itemdes').text('');
    modalBody.find('.modalBody').html('');

    var modalHeader = modalBody.find('h4.itemdes').attr('contenteditable', true).text(text);
    dataActive = $(this).closest('li').attr('data-act') == 'Y' ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
    ActiveOpt = '<p><label><input type="checkbox" id="active" class="filled-in" ' + dataActive + ' /><span>Active</span></label></p>';
    IconOpt = '<p><a href="#" class="btn" data-toggle="popover" id="changeIcon"><i class="' + li_icon + '" id="icon_element" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></p>';

    var datahtml = ActiveOpt + IconOpt;
    modalBody.find('.modalBody').html(datahtml);
    // modalBody.find('.modalBody').append(IconOpt);

    $('body').on('click', '.saveChange', function() {
      var textarea = $('.itemdes').text();
      var appendItem = textarea;
      li_element.text('').empty().append(appendItem).append(child);
      // $(this).closest("li").text('').empty().append(appendItem).append(child);
      ActiveOpt = '';
      IconOpt = '';
      // li_element = '';
    });

    // Function to check li data-Acive
    $('body').on('change', '#active', function() {
      li_element.removeAttr('data-act');
      // console.log(li_element.prop('checked'));
      if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        li_element.attr('data-act', 'Y');
        // li_element.attr('checked','checked');
      } else {
        li_element.attr('data-act', 'N');
        // li_element.removeAttr('checked');
      }



    })

  });
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- Materialized CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<!-- Modal Trigger -->
<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h4 style="width: auto; float: left;"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i></h4>
    <h4 class="itemdes">Modal Header</h4>
    <div class="modalBody">
      <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
    <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn saveChange right">Save</a>
  </div>
</div>

<ol class="example example2">
  <li data-formdesc="User" data-act="Y" data-icon="fa fa-heart">
    <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>User<a href="JavaScript:void(0)" style="visibility: visible;"><i class="fa fa-pencil modal-trigger" aria-hidden="true" data-target="modal1"></i></a>
    <ol></ol>
  </li>
  <li data-formdesc="Cash Withdrawal" data-act="Y" data-icon="">
    <i class=""></i>Cash Withdrawal<a href="JavaScript:void(0)" style="visibility: visible;"><i class="fa fa-pencil modal-trigger" aria-hidden="true" data-target="modal1"></i></a>
    <ol></ol>
  </li>
  <li data-formdesc="Branch1" data-act="Y" data-icon="fa fa-futbol-o">
    <i class="fa fa-futbol-o"></i>Branch1<a href="JavaScript:void(0)" style="visibility: visible;"><i class="fa fa-pencil modal-trigger" aria-hidden="true" data-target="modal1"></i></a>
    <ol>
      <li data-formdesc="Customer Centre" data-act="Y" data-icon="">
        <i class=""></i>Customer Centre<a href="JavaScript:void(0)" style="visibility: visible;"><i class="fa fa-pencil modal-trigger" aria-hidden="true" data-target="modal1"></i></a>
        <ol></ol>
      </li>
      <li data-formdesc="Customers Detail Listing" data-act="Y" data-icon="">
        <i class=""></i>Customers Detail Listing<a href="JavaScript:void(0)" style="visibility: visible;"><i class="fa fa-pencil modal-trigger" aria-hidden="true" data-target="modal1"></i></a>
        <ol></ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li data-formdesc="2 two" data-act="Y" data-icon="fa fa-linkedin">
    <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>2 two<a href="JavaScript:void(0)" style="visibility: visible;"><i class="fa fa-pencil modal-trigger" aria-hidden="true" data-target="modal1"></i></a>
    <ol>
      <li data-formdesc="Cash Withdrawal" data-act="Y" data-icon="">
        <i class=""></i>Cash Withdrawal<a href="JavaScript:void(0)" style="visibility: visible;"><i class="fa fa-pencil modal-trigger" aria-hidden="true" data-target="modal1"></i></a>
        <ol></ol>
      </li>
      <li data-formdesc="Till to Till Transfer" data-act="Y" data-icon="">
        <i class=""></i>Till to Till Transfer<a href="JavaScript:void(0)" style="visibility: visible;"><i class="fa fa-pencil modal-trigger" aria-hidden="true" data-target="modal1"></i></a>
        <ol>
          <li data-formdesc="Disbursement Voucher" data-act="Y" data-icon="">
            <i class=""></i>Disbursement Voucher<a href="JavaScript:void(0)" style="visibility: visible;"><i class="fa fa-pencil modal-trigger" aria-hidden="true" data-target="modal1"></i></a>
            <ol></ol>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li data-formdesc="Income Posting" data-act="Y" data-icon="">
        <i class=""></i>Income Posting<a href="JavaScript:void(0)" style="visibility: visible;"><i class="fa fa-pencil modal-trigger" aria-hidden="true" data-target="modal1"></i></a>
        <ol></ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

For example, first time I edit list item 'User' to 'Users', after I clicked on save, the item text changed well. But at second time I edit another item, let's say 'Cash Withdrawal' to 'Cash Withdrawaling', after clicked Save, the item I edited change to 'Cash Withdrawaling', but list item 'Users' that I edited previously, also change to 'Cash Withdrawaling' as well.

I did not know what is incorrect with my JavaScript. How can I correct that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At every click on .fa-pencil you add again event listeners to .saveChange and #active, using local variables like li_element, which are scoped to the callback function. This means that the second time you edit an item, two callbacks are executed, but the first still uses the previous value for li_element, thus setting the new value to the previous edited element too.

You should declare all the event listeners once, and move all the needed variables to the same level as `var child`.

This should work

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.modal').modal(); // modal

  var child;
  var li_element;
  $('body').on('click', '.fa-pencil', function(e) {


    var text = $(this).closest("li").clone() //clone the element
      .children() //select all the children
      .remove() //remove all the children
      .end() //again go back to selected element
      .text();

    child = $(this).closest("li").children();
    li_element = $(this).closest('li');
    console.log(li_element);
    var dataActive = $(this).closest('li').attr('data-act');
    var li_icon = li_element.attr('data-icon');

    var modal1 = $('#modal1');
    var modalBody = modal1.find('.modal-content');

    modalBody.find('h4.itemdes').text('');
    modalBody.find('.modalBody').html('');

    var modalHeader = modalBody.find('h4.itemdes').attr('contenteditable', true).text(text);
    dataActive = $(this).closest('li').attr('data-act') == 'Y' ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
    ActiveOpt = '<p><label><input type="checkbox" id="active" class="filled-in" ' + dataActive + ' /><span>Active</span></label></p>';
    IconOpt = '<p><a href="#" class="btn" data-toggle="popover" id="changeIcon"><i class="' + li_icon + '" id="icon_element" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></p>';

    var datahtml = ActiveOpt + IconOpt;
    modalBody.find('.modalBody').html(datahtml);
    // modalBody.find('.modalBody').append(IconOpt);
  });

  $('body').on('click', '.saveChange', function() {
      var textarea = $('.itemdes').text();
      var appendItem = textarea;
      li_element.text('').empty().append(appendItem).append(child);
      // $(this).closest("li").text('').empty().append(appendItem).append(child);
      ActiveOpt = '';
      IconOpt = '';
      // li_element = '';
    });

    // Function to check li data-Acive
    $('body').on('change', '#active', function() {
      li_element.removeAttr('data-act');
      // console.log(li_element.prop('checked'));
      if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        li_element.attr('data-act', 'Y');
        // li_element.attr('checked','checked');
      } else {
        li_element.attr('data-act', 'N');
        // li_element.removeAttr('checked');
      }

  })
})
```

Comment: I have tested your answer, and this's just working fine, thank very much.